# Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})\ncong SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for $n \geq 3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

> Given that ${SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by the set of transvection
>   matrices. Show that ${GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})\ncong {SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for $n
>  \geq 3$.

So the set of transvection matrices have $1$s on the diagonal and in some $(i,j)$ position, $i \neq j$, and $0$s elsewhere. I'm thinking it may be helpful to use abelianizations but I'm not sure how, exactly? What's a good way to go about showing ${GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})\ncong {SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: How do you prove, though, that $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ are generated by transvection matrices?

Comment: @Batominovski You can use the Smith normal form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n\geqslant 3$, then any transvection matrix is a commutator by the identity $[e_{ij},e_{jk}]= e_{ik}$. Thus the commutator of $\rm GL$ is contained in $\rm SL$ and conversely, so ${\rm SL}$ is perfect, and it follows that $[\rm GL,\rm GL]=\rm SL$ for $n\geqslant 3$. But this forces ${\rm GL}\not\simeq {\rm SL}$ since $\rm GL$ is not perfect. In fact, $\rm GL/\rm SL$ has order $2$ and an isomorphism is obtained by the determinant map that sends $A\in\rm GL$ to $\det A=\pm 1\in C_2$, which has kernel precisely $\rm SL$.

Comment: Clearly, for your argument to work, $n\geq 3$ must hold.  How do we prove the case where $n=2$?  Do you know any proof?